# jQuery - run function once

Tags: jquery, click

I have two anchor tags:

```
<a class="location" id="colorado" name="Colorado" href="#">co</a>
<a class="location" id="colorado" name="Colorado" href="#">co</a>
```

When either one of these is clicked, I want to run  a function, just once. I've looked at .one() in jQuery but I can't get this working. What I'm doing on `click()` is getting the ID attribute and storing that into a variable. Then I'm using that variable to fill out an input form. Because the anchor tags both have the class "location" the function seems to do this for all instances of the "location" class.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.location').click(function() { //when any a tag with class of location is clicked...

        var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"); //set the ID attribute into var clickedID

        $("#addressInput").val(clickedId); //set value of this input field

        setTimeout( function() {    
            $("#addressSubmit").click(); //submit the form after 1 second of the initial click    
        }, 1000); 

    });     
});
```

How can I set this so it will work any time I click on anchor tag with the class of location but it will not repeat for all anything that has a class of "location"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('.location').one('click',function() { //when any a tag with class of location is clicked...

    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"); //set the ID attribute into var clickedID

    $("#addressInput").val(clickedId); //set value of this input field

    setTimeout( function() {    
        $("#addressSubmit").click(); //submit the form after 1 second of the initial click    
    }, 1000); 

});
```

Per the site description: "Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type."

**EDIT**: you only want to run once, eh?

```
$('.location').on('click',function() {        
    // set value of this input field, and 
    document.getElementById('addressInput').value = this.id;

    // remove click handlers
    $('.location').off('click');

    // submit the form after 1 second delay
    setTimeout( function() {    
        document.getElementById('addressSubmit').submit();
    }, 1000); 
});
```

This will remove the click event on the first run of it. I also took the liberty of de-jQuerying a bit ... all the functions you're running can easily be done in pure JS. I also changed you triggering the click event to just submitting the form ... I assume that is what you were looking to do there.

[jsFiddle provided](http://jsfiddle.net/UWQnz/).

Comment: I think he wants it to run only once period, though; not once per button.

Comment: ah i see, then i can mod as needed.

Comment: that's not really delegating, you're still attaching the events to the <a>'s. delegate would be `$(document).on('click', '.location:not(.clicked)', function(){})`. and in any case, using namespaces is the correct (and core) approach to have multiple handlers on the same event

Comment: good point, i removed that answer. taking the cue from u, ill just kick back and comment on what is the correct way to do it without actually showing it. cool stuff about namespaces though, i was unaware of that.

Comment: Thanks for including the jsFiddle. I would like to be able to click back and forth... http://www.msofco.com/locations-test/ is the page. It's a password protected WordPress page. The password is 'stackoverflow' - you'll see you can click on each state abbreviation (ca or co) and then the other, but not after that. I suppose the .one() is doing that. Ideally, I want the user to be able click any abbreviation as much as they need for searching. I suppose the way I asked the question led you in the wrong direction.

Comment: Okay I have it working how I need now. I used your first answer and instead of `$('.location').on('click',function() { ` I changed it to `$('.location').click(function() {` and I'm not getting the strange loop form before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: not sure why ... `.click(function()` is literally just shorthand for `.on('click',function()`, but regardless glad everything worked out.

Answer (score 1):

using your code, it would be

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var locations =$('.location');
    locations.on('click', function() { //when any a tag with class of location is clicked...

        var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"); //set the ID attribute into var clickedID

        $("#addressInput").val(clickedId); //set value of this input field
        locations.off('click'); //remove the rest of the handlers
        setTimeout( function() {    
            $("#addressSubmit").click(); //submit the form after 1 second of the initial click    
        }, 1000); 

    });     
});
```

altough it would be cleaner to use the on/off on the container of the `.location`s, using the delegate style (with 3 parameters)

Comment: This is a good solution as long as you don't want multiple `click` functions on any of the buttons, which seems like a safe bet. But it's worth realizing that that `locations.off('click')` will remove all click events on the locations, not just the one added here.

Comment: @user1618143 in that case, it's easily addressed using namespaces, using `'click.address'` on the event name, for example

Answer (score 0):

First issue I notice is that you have two items with the same id, change the second tag's id. If one() does not work for you try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

    // Bind to the click event
    $('.location').on('click', function() { //when any a tag with class of location is clicked...

        var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"); //set the ID attribute into var clickedID

        $("#addressInput").val(clickedId); //set value of this input field

        // Unbind the event
        $('.location').off('click');

        setTimeout( function() { 

            $("#addressSubmit").click(); //submit the form after 1 second of the initial click

        }, 1000); 

    });


});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run the function when the first button is clicked, and then never again, no matter which button is clicked? There are more elegant solutions, but the easy method is to use a simple flag:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    flag = true;
    $('.location').click(function() { //when any a tag with class of location is clicked...
        if(!flag) return;
        flag = false;

        var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"); //set the ID attribute into var clickedID

        $("#addressInput").val(clickedId); //set value of this input field

        setTimeout( function() {    
            $("#addressSubmit").click(); //submit the form after 1 second of the initial click    
        }, 1000); 

    });     
});
```